# How to list system calls and library calls in Unix?

Tags: ubuntu, system-calls

Where do I find all system calls and library calls?

Can I list them?

How to find out which ones occur most often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you want the system/library calls which are made from a particular program, not all of them.

`strace` shows all the external calls from an executable program. If the program has a graphic user interface, there'll be thousands of them - make it difficult to analyze them 'on-screen'.

To save all the calls, you can redirect `strace`'s output to a file:

```
strace your_executable 2> my_log_file
```

which will close when exiting the program. You can then view/search the file in any text viewer/editor. More information is available from `man strace`, or from eg. [linux.die.net/man/1/strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). [This page shows some interesting ways to use `strace`](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent//2015/12/10/introduction-to-strace.html).

**For completeness**: Stephen Harris suggested below:

> FWIW, strace -o log_file -f your_executable may be better; the -o flag
>   causes strace to send output there, and the -ff means that if the
>   program calls fork() then this child process is also followed.
>   Depending on the app -ff might be better, so each child process data
>   is in its own log file. strace shows system calls; ltrace can show
>   library calls.

**And even more** from Mark Plotnick:

> Yeah, ltrace -c -S command... is what to use to show a count of
>   library and system calls.

Comment: You are right! I need the system/library calls of /bin/date. Now it makes sense. This assignment should have been more clear. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, `strace -o log_file -f your_executable` may be better; the `-o` flag causes `strace` to send output there, and the `-ff` means that if the program calls `fork()` then this child process is also followed.  Depending on the app `-ff` might be better, so each child process data is in its own log file.  `strace` shows system calls; `ltrace` can show library calls.

Comment: Yeah, `ltrace -c -S command...` is what to use to show a count of library and system calls.